# How to update multiple rows in Google sheets using Zapier?

Tags: google-sheets, zapier

I have a client that has a wordpress site with the Ultimate Member plugin installed and they have a committee that monitors a google sheet that is currently set up to add new members as they sign up with Zapier, but no way to update the sheet as current members update their profile.

I can't seem to get anything to work so I am asking here if anyone knows a way to accomplish this?

I have tried using the Google sheet integration to update the rows with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team. Great question!

You can't update multiple rows in one call with Zapier, but you can trigger multiple update operations. There are docs about updating rows [here](https://zapier.com/apps/google-sheets/help#updating-rows). If you pair that with an "Updated Profile" trigger, then it should work as expected. I don't see "Ultimate Member" listed as an existing integration, so you may need to create that trigger yourself with our [developer platform](https://zapier.com/platform).

Comment: ok, thanks, I will look into that.  Ultimate Member appears to extend the WP User profile, the integration is done with WP All Export, which you do have an integration for.